# How install alluxio1.2 on openstack

Tags: installation, openstack, alluxio

I try to install alluxio1.2 on a VM centos on openstack with spark and hdfs but the installation doesn't works. Spark and hdfs are already install and work

```
    ERROR logger.type (AlluxioMaster.java:main) - Uncaught exception while running Alluxio master, stopping it and exiting.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
        at alluxio.web.UIWebServer.startWebServer(UIWebServer.java:164)
        at alluxio.master.AlluxioMaster.startServingWebServer(AlluxioMaster.java:467)
        at alluxio.master.AlluxioMaster.startServing(AlluxioMaster.java:452)
        at alluxio.master.AlluxioMaster.startServing(AlluxioMaster.java:447)
        at alluxio.master.AlluxioMaster.start(AlluxioMaster.java:389)
        at alluxio.master.AlluxioMaster.main(AlluxioMaster.java:86)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
        at alluxio.web.UIWebServer.startWebServer(UIWebServer.java:154)
        ... 5 more
```

Are there a special installation to install alluxio on one openstack machine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Alluxio master's web UI cannot start because the address is already in use. This happens if the port is taken by another process. Alluxio web UI uses the port 19999 for the web UI by default. If you expect another process to be using that port, you can change the Alluxio master web UI port by changing the configuration parameter (http://www.alluxio.org/docs/master/en/Configuration-Settings.html#master-configuration), `alluxio.master.web.port`, to another port number.

Comment: thank you, I fix the problem. I modified the port and the java version. (Alluxio works with jdk1.8.77 but it doesn't work with a more recent version). To fix jdk regression, you need Upgrade Jetty (for information :) )